# CoreData error failed

Tags: core-data, ios6, nsobject

In my application i have used following code with core data,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface Adduser : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * contact_no;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * address;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * response;
@end
```

Method

```
-(IBAction)signup:(id)sender
{
Registration *adduser=[Registration new];//<-CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Registration'
adduser.name=txt1.text;
adduser.password=txt2.text;
adduser.email=txt3.text;
adduser.contact_no=txt5.text;
adduser.address=txtvu.text;
}
```

When i try to implement is shows the

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Registration'
```

with SIGABRT error?what wrong with my code?Please help

Comment: You need to read the documentation. You property assessor are incorrect they should read `dynamic` instead of `retain`. Let CoreData generate the model classes for you so you don't have to worry about it. Once that's out of the way, the answer below is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an instance of a managed object class you need to:

```
Registration *adduser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Registration" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Comment: Minor note: Casting to `Registration *` is not necessary because `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` returns an `id`.

Comment: Edited thanks, typing on my iPad and couldn't remember at the time.